# How to add urls of two apps in urls.py single project in django?

Tags: django, django-urls

[image]

Project1 contains app1 amd app1.. but i dont understand how to put urls of both apps

App1 views ----------->> urls at project1 level

App2 views------------->>urls at project1 level

Comment: Paste your code, do not link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in importing the views, you are importing both the views with the same name(ie, views), either you can user

```
from jobApp import views as x
from mumjob import views as y
```

And then:

```
path('url1/', x.views1),
path('url2/', y.views2),
```

But this is a bad practice, you can import directly all the function by the command,

```
from jobApp.views imports FUNCTION_NAME
```

And then:

```
path('url1/', FUNCTION_NAME)
```

Hope this helps!